# Sailpoint IIQ integration With Microsoft Sentinel

Tags: sailpoint

Hello I want to connect the Sailpoint IIQ with Microsoft Sentinel. I cannot find any connector either in Sentinel or Sailpoint.

Should I do this enabling Syslog and using Syslog connector in Sentinel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that.
First enabling syslog in SailPoint IIQ and once the syslog is enabled, configure the syslog connector in Sentinel.